# Does jaws support the aria attribute aria-owns?

Tags: html, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I have a page which I am supposed to make accessible without too many changes.

One combo box in the page is coded so that on clicking upon an input box, the contents of a div are copied into an iframe element in the same page, and that iframe is made visible below the input box.

I added aria-live to the container iframe, and Jaws would read the iframe that forms the drop down whenever it came up, but how do i link up the two such that Jaws focus can be shifted to the iframe whenever it is made visible and not just reading it out as a dynamic update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having a hard time understanding exactly how the UI is supposed to work based on your description. However, I can tell you that JAWS does not support aria-owns.

If you consult [Freedom Scientific's documentation page](http://www.freedomscientific.com/documentation/screen-readers.asp), you'll find a Word document laying out JAWS' support for ARIA.  It does not list aria-owns.

Comment: Yes i did fin it out later.. Had a word with Freedom scientific tech team and they did not mention anything about this too.